# SSO against Win AD in Java Play. How to get Win username?

Tags: java, authentication, playframework-2.0, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I have an app in java play 2.1.x. I need to get user windows username
and check it against Win AD. I know how to do check against Win AD from for ex. [here](http://mhimu.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/active-directory-authentication-using-javajndi/).
But I have no idea how to get Win username in java play. 
I was looking into Waffle, did't found way how to use it with play.

If it's not possible - I'll be using existing play authentication to get 
username/pass.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the windows username is a client side info. You cannot obtain that info directly via Playframework. You will have to get it via a client-side info and then pass it on to the windows AD.

It would seem that obtaining the username on client side requires either :

- Windows Explorer for Active X
- Or a client side installed DLL

Once you have that, you can use whatever java library to connect to windows AD and check it.

Comment: Thank you. I found the way for getting it if user uses IE:
    
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var username = WinNetwork.UserName;